# How to search WITHIN subfolders in Thunar File Manager?

Tags: linux, xubuntu, thunar

I have GalliumOS, it's basically a Xubuntu for Chromebooks.

So, when I installed Firefox, the icon turned to a dumb theme. So I read oneline that the icon is located in /usr/share/icons, great!

But when I go there, I'm met with TONS of folders, and don't know which one has Firefox for the icon. When I type in the search, nothing, it only searches for the folder names but not INSIDE every folder in the current folder I'm in.

I go to Google this for help, but nothing relevant comes up. Is there anyway I can search inside the other sub-folders from the one I'm currently in? Sorta like Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Thunar itself does not implement a recursive search.
E.g. `catfish` can be used for that ... you may want to add a `Thunar` custom action for using `catfish`.

```
Name: Search files inside…
Command: catfish %f
File pattern: *
```

Check as well the section ["custom actions" in the thunar Wiki](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions)